# How to verify if one xml is a subset of another in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have two Xml files, I will call the first one `Input Xml` and the second one `Template Xml`. The `Template Xml` is a static Xml and I want to verify if the `Template Xml` is a subset of the `Input Xml`. How do I achieve this in C#?

By subset I mean that I want to verify if the Xml Tags and Attributes mentioned in the `Template Xml` are present in the `Input Xml` with the same values.

Comment: I would reccommed using an XML Schema file (XSD) instead, unless you don't have a choice. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema

Comment: I want to ensure that certain tags and attributes with specific values are present, but don't care about additional tags. Also, the XML already has an XSD which I cannot modify. Maybe I am missing something, could you elaborate how can I use XSD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use xpath to query both XML files and compare their value.

you can find reference to xpath on the following link: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

Answer (score 0):

Conatains is very open ended. What about orders of tag and attributes... it has to be in same order and what about tag depth. Assuming just matching tags from template if it exist in xml (irrelevant of depth), you can use following extension method.

```
    public static bool SupportsTemplate(this XmlDocument xmlDoc, XmlNode template) {
        bool found = true;
        var nodes = template.ChildNodes;
        foreach(XmlNode node in nodes){
            found = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//" + node.Name) == null ? false : true;
            if (!found) break;
            if (node.HasChildNodes)
                found = xmlDoc.SupportsTemplate(node);
            if (!found) break;
        }
        return found;
    }
```

Not tested & not optimized code (call like xmlDoc.SupportsTemplate(template.DocumentElement). Implement something similar. You can extend this to check attribute as well.